# to_xml always throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm on Rails 3.1

I've pasted an example below, but Calling to_xml on *any* model throws this error. I've tried everything but I'm it's the sort of thing someone would have seen before. Does it ring any bells for anyone?

```
1.8.7 :004 > Person.first.to_xml
  Person Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` LIMIT 1
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:135:in `to_xs'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:135:in `_escape'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:140:in `_escape_quote'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:320:in `_attr_value'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:308:in `_insert_attributes'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:306:in `each'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:306:in `_insert_attributes'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:284:in `_special'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:250:in `instruct!'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/activemodel-3.1.1/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:93:in `serialize'
    from /home/khughes/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rails31/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/serializers/xml_serializer.rb:175:in `to_xml'
    from (irb):4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same issue some time ago, do you have hpricot gem bundled into the project? if so, try to remove it from the Gemfile, run `bundle` and check if to_xml works

there's a solution that worked for me:
https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot/issues/53 ( see `smeevil`'s post )

Comment: That was it! Thanks, I don't think I'd have ever tracked that down.